# How in VBA Excel get the range of arguments from formula in the cell?

Tags: vba, excel, formula, cells

The issue:

1. I have a cell with a formula with some cells in this workbook as
   arguments
2. I need to access those arguments using VBA somehow and change their color

Thank you in advance

Comment: do you have any code or screenshots to show us?  your question isn't very descriptive

Comment: What have you tried till now? Based on what condition you want to change the color of cell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all references to a cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248820/find-all-references-to-a-cell)

Comment: I wrote the code that extracts cell addresses and access them directly and I was wondering, whether there is a simpler way to do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy if the formula is simple.  Say **A1** contains:

```
=SUM(B2:B20,D9)
```

Select the cell and run:

```
Sub ColorMeElmo()
    Dim s As String

    ActiveCell.Precedents.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
End Sub
```

to get:

[image]

This will only work if the `Precedences` is directly applicable.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This code does exactly what I asked for.
Will change now my 150+ lines with this one :)

Comment: If there is any way to access the precedents in the closed workbook?

Comment: @PG_Develop  I am not aware of a way...............open a new question, perhaps some one else knows.